# Does Data Sms Count Towards Android Sms Limit?

Tags: android, sms, limit, smsmanager

I understand that Android has a 30 sms in 30 minutes limit, but does this also apply to data sms? Thanks!

Comment: I've not dug through all the relevant source code, but it looks like they do count toward the limit. It appears that the count is based on raw PDUs alone, not the message type. Btw, the limit and time period is ultimately set by the manufacturer/carrier, so they might not be those default values.

Comment: Thank you for your input, sir! :)